# Can I perform a class method after a delay?

Tags: objective-c

I'm inside a class method, and I want to trigger another class method, from the same class, after a delay. Doesn't appear that I can use

```
[MyClass performSelector:@selector(myMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1]
```

Any other options?

Edited:

My bad. I assumed that call wasn't available within a class method, because it wasn't auto-completing as I wrote it. As a couple of people have pointed out here, it actually works fine. Not sure why it didn't autocomplete in my case, but learned a lesson about making assumptions when this happens. Thanks everyone.

Comment: what do you mean by delay? Why can't you just call the 2nd method after the first?

Comment: I mean a delay, of n seconds, before the method is called. If a certain condition isn't met, I want to attempt the method call again after n seconds. No problem in an instance method, but performSelector:afterDelay: doesn't seem to be available from within a class method.

Comment: In Objective-C, all class objects are instances of the base class. So if MyClass inherits from NSObject, then all *instance* methods of NSObject are also *class* methods of MyClass. You can read more at http://www.sealiesoftware.com/blog/archive/2009/04/14/objc_explain_Classes_and_metaclasses.html if you're curious about why...

Comment: The call as written works fine. Did you try it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You use `-class` to get an actual reference to the class and then message it like so:

```
[[MyClass class] performSelector:@selector(myClassMethod) withObject:nil afterDelay:1.0];
```

Comment: Thanks. Out of interest, why do I need to use [[MyClass class] to invoke [performSelector:afterDelay:], but to call a method immediately, I can just write [MyClass myMethod]?

Comment: In Objective-C classes are actually objects which provide sort of a template for its instances. If you write `[MyClass myClassMethod]` it's basically the same as writing `[[MyClass class] myClassMethod]` but the compiler will take care of it so you don't have to. When you message a class dynamically with `-performSelector:` the compiler can't handle that for you and you have to get a reference to the class manually.

Comment: @JamesWhite you don't. `[MyClass performSelector...]` should work fine. If you wanted to pass the class as an argument, `[MyClass class]` would be needed though.

Comment: [MyClass class] is unnecessary. The original works as written.

Comment: But because `-performSelector:` is defined as an instance method, `[MyClass class]` seems more appropriate to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use dispatch_after

```
double delayInSeconds = 2.0;
dispatch_time_t popTime = dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(delayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC));
dispatch_after(popTime, dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^(void){
    [MyClass myClassMethod];
});
```